# Check phone's internet connection continuously, even after the app is closed

Tags: java, android, notifications, connection

I need to continuously check the phone's internet connection from inside my application, even after the application is closed, and send notification when the internet is off.

I searched a lot and couldn't find any sample or clue or answer... can anyone help me how can I implement this?

Comment: As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I found the answer..:)

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted it here and accepted as the correct one.